# SSL for Webserver

Tags: ssl

I am totally not familiar with SSL and all tutorials are pretty confusing for me.

I want to ask you one thing - I have from rapidssl this two certs: intermediate.crt & web_server.crt. I had to combine

```
 cat intermediate.crt >> web_server.crt
```

But how I will get priv.key for my certificate? I am using nginx + debian.

Comment: How did you generate your CSR? Your private key would have been generated as part of that process.

Comment: Hello, I`ve got complete certificate from RapidSSL. I did not created any CSR. So I tryed to follow this https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17664 but didnt work.

Comment: So you did not do [this step](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17540) before getting your certificate from RapidSSL?

Comment: mhm. Nope, Actually I totally missed it. I will try it and let you know. But thank you, I apologize for my stupidity.

Comment: So I have now .key and .csr .. what to do next I am supposed to create new certification, or use that one from email what sent me RapidSSL?

Comment: Back to my first question. RapidSSL cannot generate a `web_server.crt` without a CSR - so how did you provide them with a CSR?

Comment: I generated it via

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr`

Comment: I tryed to use server.key and web_server.crt provided by RapidSSL and I have this error
`SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/server.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate`

Comment: bumb please :) I dont know how to solve it :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I had wrong key ... sorry for my mistake.